# how to make ipad keyboard type or language to french in HTML5

Tags: html, keyboard

I have app which is in french i want that when user input any data it should french keyboard on ipad to input is there any way to get this fix.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to disappoint you, but what you're asking is simply not possible.
User can only change their language in the settings.

However you can give the user an "English" keyboard if you choose (or ask them their preference)

you do this using: UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable

You can change keyboard directly on the keyboard by pressing "globe icon" on the bottom row.

First, you have to enable those language for input in Settings. Then pressing the globe button on the keyboard would toggle between those languages.